# cordova plugin barcode scanner doesn't open the scan

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I have a problem with the barcode scanner plugin (I'm not a genius and I don't know well how to programm a web-app.).
I use phonegap and cordova and I've tried to do a web-app that scan a barcode after a click on a link.
I've installed the plugin, before with this command line:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-barcodescanner
```

and I write this js code:

```
function scan(){
 cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  }, 
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  }
 );
}
```

in html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="scan()">Scan</a>
```

But when I click on the link, It doesn't happen anything.
If I put an alert after: function scan(){, it show
if I put an alert after: cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(, doesn't do anything.
So, I tried to uninstall the plugin and install it with this command line:

```
cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
```

With the same js and html code, but it doesn't work yet.
So, I uninstall the plugin and I try to install it with:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git
```

But anything yet.
I search a lot and I try a lot of solutions!
I use cordova 5.0.0 and I try the plugin on android 4.4 and IOS.
I also installed the plugin camera.
So, please, help me! Where is the error?
I followed all the solutions that I've find on the web and on stackoverflow.
The code always crashes after:

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
```

Can anyone help me, please?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you waiting for the cordova deviceready event before you start your script?

Comment: Yes, I'm waiting for the cordova deviceready event before start my script.

Comment: Write your plugin code in onDeviceReady event, Make sure you had include cordova.js in html file.

Comment: Have we got to put the function scan() into onDeviceReady?
function onDeviceReady () { function scan(){ cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function (result) { alert("We got a barcode\n" + "Result: " + result.text + "\n" + "Format: " + result.format + "\n" + "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled); }, function (error) { alert("Scanning failed: " + error); } ); } } 
Is it correct?
I'm sure that I have included cordova.js

Answer (score 0):

First of all can you check your code in firefox with firebug, see if it is giving some error which can let you to do so or you can try other library which is intelXDK

```
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.barcode.scan",function(evt){});
```

Comment: I try the app with firebug. When I click on the button, firebug returns the error "cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan is not defined". Do you know why? I include barcodescanner.js and cordova.js, and others js like jquery and jquery mobile. What can be the problem? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the feature to the config.xml in case of Android as below:

```
<feature name="BarcodeScanner">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" />
</feature>
```